# Implementing QR decomposition in C

Tags: c, debugging, qr-decomposition

**Problem solved**

It seems I accidently wrote j where it should be 0 on the line

```
matrix_column_subtract(Q,i,matrix_column_multiply(T,0,r),j);
```

Which should be

```
matrix_column_subtract(Q,i,matrix_column_multiply(T,0,r),0);
```

---

I'm implementing QR decomposition in C using my matrix implementations and various helper functions. I wrote the main function to decompose a matrix A into two matrices Q and R by using the Gram-Schmidt process:

[image: qr]

**matrix.c**

```
#define TYPE double
#define FLAG "%7.3f"

typedef struct {
  TYPE **array;    /* Pointer to an array of type TYPE */
  int rows;       /* Number of rows */
  int cols;       /* Number of columns */
} matrix;

/* Decomposes the matrix A into QR */
void QRdecompose(matrix *A, matrix *Q, matrix *R) {

  /* Using the Gram-Schmidt process */

  /* Temporary vector T and S used in calculations */
  matrix *T = create_matrix(A->rows, 1);
  matrix *S = create_matrix(A->rows, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < A->cols; i++) {

    //Qi = Ui
    matrix_copy_column(A,i,Q,i);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

      //r[j,i] = Qj^T * Ui
      matrix_copy_column(Q,j,T,0);
      matrix_copy_column(A,i,S,0);
      TYPE r = 0;
      for (int k=0; k<A->rows; k++) {
        r += T->array[k][0] * S->array[k][0];
      }

      R->array[j][i] = r;
      matrix_column_subtract(Q,i,matrix_column_multiply(T,0,r),j);

    }

    //r[i,i] = ||Qi||
    R->array[i][i] = vector_length(Q,i);
    //Qi = Qi/r[i,i]
    matrix_column_divide(Q,i,R->array[i][i]);

  }

  //free_matrix(T);
  //free_matrix(S);

}
```

Functions that I created and used were

```
/* Creates a matrix and returns a pointer to the struct */
matrix* create_matrix(int rows, int cols) {

  /* Allocate memory for the matrix struct */
  matrix *array = malloc(sizeof(matrix));

  array->rows = rows;
  array->cols = cols;

  /* Allocate enough memory for all the rows in the first matrix */
  array->array = calloc(rows, sizeof(TYPE*));

  /* Enough memory for all the columns */
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    array->array[i] = calloc(cols,sizeof(TYPE));
  }

  return array;
}

/* Creates a matrix from a stack based array and returns a pointer to the struct */
matrix* create_matrix_from_array(int rows, int cols, TYPE m[][cols]) {

  /* Allocate memory for the matrix struct */
  matrix *array = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
  array->rows = rows;
  array->cols = cols;

  /* Allocate memory for the matrix */
  array->array = malloc(sizeof(TYPE*) * rows);

  /* Allocate memory for each array inside the matrix */
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    array->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * cols);
  }

  /* Populate the matrix with m's values */
  for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      array->array[row][col] = m[row][col];
    }
  }

  return array;
}
/* Copies a matrix column from msrc at column col1 to mdst at column col2 */
void matrix_copy_column(matrix *msrc, int col1, matrix *mdst,int col2) {
  for (int i=0; i<msrc->rows; i++) {
    mdst->array[i][col2] = msrc->array[i][col1];
  }
}

/* Subtracts m2's column c2 from m1's column c1 */
matrix* matrix_column_subtract(matrix *m1, int c1, matrix *m2, int c2) {
  for (int i=0; i<m1->rows; i++) {
      m1->array[i][c1] -= m2->array[i][c2];
  }
  return m1;
}

/* Returns the length of the vector column in m */
double vector_length(matrix *m,int column) {
  double length = 0;
  for (int row=0; row<m->rows; row++) {
    length += m->array[row][column] * m->array[row][column];
  }
  return sqrt(length);
}

/* Divides the matrix column c in m by k */
matrix* matrix_column_divide(matrix *m, int c, TYPE k) {
  for (int i=0; i<m->rows; i++) {
    m->array[i][c] /= k;
  }
  return m;
}

/* Multiplies the matrix column c in m by k */
matrix* matrix_column_multiply(matrix *m, int c, TYPE k) {
  for (int i=0; i<m->rows; i++) {
    m->array[i][c] *= k;
  }
  return m;
}

/* Debugging purposes only */
void print_matrix(matrix *m) {
  for (int row = 0; row < m->rows; row++) {
    printf("[");
    for (int col = 0; col < m->cols - 1; col++) {
      printf(FLAG", ", m->array[row][col]);
    }
    printf(FLAG, m->array[row][m->cols-1]);
    printf("]\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

However there is a bug in my QRdecompose() function where the last column of the Q matrix is incorrect i.e the values are different. I have been debugging for 4 hours using GDB in Eclipse but I'm really stuck so I thought I'd turn over to SE for some assistance.

**main.c**

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

  TYPE a[3][3] = { { 12, -51, 4 }, { 6, 167, -68 }, { -4, 24, -41 } };

  matrix *A = create_matrix_from_array(3,3,a);
  matrix *Q = create_matrix(3,3);
  matrix *R = create_matrix(3,3);
  QRdecompose(A,Q,R);

  print_matrix(A);
  print_matrix(Q);
  print_matrix(R);
  return 0;

}
```

I tested my code using the matrix:

[image: matrix]

The output of my program produces

```
Q
[  0.857,  -0.394,   0.204]
[  0.429,   0.903,  -0.792]
[ -0.286,   0.171,  -0.575]

R
[ 14.000,  21.000, -14.000]
[  0.000, 175.000, -70.000]
[  0.000,   0.000,  78.262]
```

Where the actual answer should be

```
 Q

 0.857 -0.394 -0.331
 0.429  0.903  0.034
-0.286  0.171 -0.943

 R

 14.000  21.000 -14.000
  0.000 175.000 -70.000
  0.000   0.000  35.000
```

The rows/columns of Q may be different in the model answer but the actual rows/columns of my output are still correct except for the last column.

The problem seems to happen on the last iteration of the first loop; I printed the matrix R inside:

```
[ 14.000,   0.000,   0.000]
[  0.000,   0.000,   0.000]
[  0.000,   0.000,   0.000]

[ 14.000,  21.000,   0.000]
[  0.000, 175.000,   0.000]
[  0.000,   0.000,   0.000]

[ 14.000,  21.000, -14.000]
[  0.000, 175.000, -70.000]
[  0.000,   0.000,  78.262]
```

I'm not sure if there are any bugs in my helper functions because I checked them before I started testing code however the logic inside the QRdecompose() function seems a bit off. Aside from memory leaks which I haven't covered yet. Can anyone see any problems in QRdecompose() Am I missing something?

Sorry for the huge amount of code
Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Well, which is the *exact* line where behaviour diverged from what you expected?  Can you reproduce the problem with a simpler matrix (e.g. identity matrix)?

Comment: I didn't think about using the identity matrix! I just tested it now and that works fine however the problem occurs on the last iteration of the loop it seems. I'm not sure which line exactly, I'm testing it now.

Comment: Cool.  What I'm getting at is that you ought to be able to debug until you find a *specific* calculation that diverges from what should have happened.  Once you've found that, working backwards to identify the root cause should be easy.  (Using simple test-cases generally makes this easier, but isn't critical.)

Comment: Ok I found the bug! It seems I accidently wrote j instead of 0 on this line: matrix_column_subtract(Q,i,matrix_column_multiply(T,0,r),j);

Comment: Excellent - glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link for more details
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32540518)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).